# Switching from Devise to OmniAuth with Rails 5. Keeping Devise or not?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, rubygems, ruby-on-rails-5, omniauth

So I have been using **Devise gem** for users to sign up with email, but now I want to switch to Twitter login using **OmniAuth gem**. I'm a bit confused with the transition.

Should I still keep Devise Gem or remove it completely and create a custom User table to store users' personal and Twitter details?

Thank you tons!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No you can use Devise Omniauthable option. check the instructions [here](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/OmniAuth:-Overview). You will not have to separate users in different tables, just follow the instructions to add twitter sign on and add the appropriate fields to your users table(`provider` and `uid`)

Comment: Hi, thanks for answer! Yes, I know Devise can be used with Omniauth, I was just wondering if there are any benefits of keeping Devise when I'm certain of not using email sign up ever. Thank you, Btw this is for an unreleased project. So no use  signups yet.

Comment: Well, devise uses warden underneath, and that makes your authentication easier to reason about.. Also all the built in features like locking and sign in time registering and view helpers come out of the box even though the implementation is not that difficult. But I do suggest you stick with devise.. then you're safe of all the session handling and so on and there's less room for errors.

Comment: I see, so even though I don't use sign up/in features of devise, I should keep it by connecting OmniAuth to it. Continue using Devise's User database table to store OmniAuth details and using OmniAuth only for Twitter login/out.

Comment: Yes, I  would suggest that.

Comment: Thanks mate. Currently I've been working on that. Trying to solve 9873468 errors I have been getting on the way :)